# How do I deal with segfault ? C language

Tags: c

Suppose we are given a task to write a function that add 2 numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** av) {
    int a = atoi(av[1]);
    int b = atoi(av[2]);
    add_and_print(a, b)
    return 0;

}
```

It works fine untill I pass following code:

```
./a.out
```

Just passing empty strings. Then it writes the following:

```
1495 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could you please explain what is the problem and how do I deal with it ?

Comment: Check if the command line parameters were passed before trying to use them. This is what `argc` is for

Comment: if argc == 0, then print(' '). Do you mean this solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I deal with segfault

The segfault happens because of a bug in your code.

So, you prevent it happening in the first place, by not writing buggy code.

In general though, the segfault makes it easy to find out exactly what bug triggered it: just run your program under the debugger, and it will stop exactly where the segfault occurs.

> Could you please explain what is the problem

In this code:

```
int a = atoi(av[1]);
```

the expression `av[1]` is only legal if there are *at least two* elements in array `av` (since we start indexing at zero). If there is only one element, this code attempts to read beyond the end of the array.

Since the array is based on the command-line arguments, you must *check* it. You need to do this for *all* inputs from users, files, even other parts of your own code. Don't just assume the user did what you expected (or the file contained what you expected, or the caller passed the right values). This is a bug.

```
if (argc >= 2) {
    // now it is safe to refer to av[1]
    a = atoi(av[1]);
}
```

You have to do something similar for `av[2]`, for the same reason.

A common solution might be instead

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Syntax: %s a b\n"
               "\n"
               "Two integer arguments are required.", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    add_and_print(a, b)
}
```

I'm just assuming that `argc` is at least 1, and that `argv[0]` is the name of the program. You can check this too if you want perfectly portable code.

Note that you might *also* want to check whether the arguments are really integers.

Answer (score 3):

`argc` contains the number of arguments provided to the program, and if you don't check it then you might get a segfault trying to read from `argv`. You can display an error message and exit if there aren't enough arguments:

```c
if (argc < 3) {
    puts("Please provide 2 numbers as command line arguments.");
    return 1;
}
```